# select table.object_type and select table.* don't return the same value for object_type

Tags: select, enterprise-architect

I'm trying to select all the 'Application Functions' linked to an object. So I've read the following query:

```
select 
other.ea_guid as CLASSGUID, other.object_type as CLASSTYPE,
obj.name, 
other.*
from  t_object as obj
join (
        select t_connector.start_object_id as Object2_id, t_object.* from t_object 
                join t_connector on t_connector.end_object_id=t_object.Object_id
                where t_object.object_type =  'Application Function'
        union
        select t_connector.end_object_id as Object2_id, t_object.*  from t_object  
                join t_connector on t_connector.start_object_id=t_object.Object_id
                where t_object.object_type =  'Application Function'

        ) as other on obj.Object_id=other.Object2_id
where obj.object_id = 143299
```

And it is empty.

Without the `where` clause, it returns:
[image: select * result]

But if I change in the select the `other.*` by named columns like `other.object_type, object_name` then column `obj.name`gets empty and `other.object_type`as another value:
[image: named select result]

I thing this difference explains why my select doesn't work. But how to explain and resolve this ?

Comment: IIRC the text in `object_type` is mangled by EA in some way. Will have a look later.

Comment: Can I assume that "Application Function" is a metatype from your own MDG?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Sparx to answer this. All I can tell you is that in the _docked_ properties window, the *type* of the object is 'Application Function' and its *stereotype* is 'B_ApplicationFunction'. While in the _floating_ Properties window, the *type* is 'B_ApplicationFunction'. There is already some confusion there.

Comment: If you ask a question about that I can give an answer. The notes here are too short for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EA does some special *magic* to some of the fields when returned by a query.

It does so based on the exact name of the returned field such as `Object_Type` or `Note`
To avoid this make sure to give those fields a different alias. e.g. `Object_Type as theRealType`

In this case I'm going to assume you are looking for ArchiMate application functions. The fact that this is an Application function is actually stored in the **Stereotype** rather than the **Object_Type**

A query like this should return all ArchiMate Application Functions linked to an object with id 143299

```
select o2.Object_ID AS CLASSGUID, o2.Object_Type AS CLASSTYPE, o2.Object_Type as theRealObjectType,
o2.*
from t_object o 
inner join t_connector c on c.Connector_ID in (c.Start_Object_ID, c.End_Object_ID)
inner join t_object o2 on o2.Object_ID in (c.Start_Object_ID, c.End_Object_ID)
                        and o2.Object_ID <> o.Object_ID
where o.Stereotype = 'ArchiMate_ApplicationFunction'
and o2.Object_ID = 143299
```

*This query has been written and tested on an SQL Server repository. It might need tweaking if you want to use it on a .eap file (MS Access SQL Syntax)*

Comment: The 2 propositions are working well (to alias the column name and to search on the stereotype). However (and I'm not that familiar with Sparx) is searching on Stereotype robust to futher modifications on the model ? I used a `where lower (t_object.stereotype) like '%application%function%'`for more robustness. Maybe is this overkill